# node.js:201 process.nextTick error?

Tags: node.js, meteor

So I'm messing around with meteor, and out of no where I received this error? What is it asking me to change?

```
node.js:201
    throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
          ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at /Users/devinandrews/my_cool_app/.meteor/local/build/server/server.js:109:21
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function.<anonymous>(/Users/devinandrews/my_cool_app/.meteor/local/build/server/underscore.js:76:11)
at /Users/devinandrews/my_cool_app/.meteor/local/build/server/server.js:95:7
Exited with code: 1
Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

Thanks guys..

Comment: Can you share some code and/or narrow down a repro?  the line numbers and errors mean nothing to others without code

Answer (score 0):

You need to look through the code and see what it's doing in server.js around 109. It is probably working with a network connection that is being abruptly terminated. Are you doing anything like accessing your site with curl and CTRL-C-ing it while it's connected to your server? Because of the disconnected nature of vanilla node.js stack traces, we need to see the code to help you debug this.

Comment: not trying to access with curl or ctrl c-ing it... in 109 area it is this:     _.each(info.load, function (filename) {
      var code = fs.readFileSync(path.join(bundle_dir, filename));
      require('vm').runInThisContext(code, filename, true);
    });

Comment: Are there installs/updates to your app happening while the server is running. It seems like maybe that readFileSync is throwing an error when the underlying file is unexpectedly truncated or removed.

Answer (score 0):

This error comes up when you have a syntax error. Perhaps you are missing a closing brace in `server.js`?

Comment: I received the error without even touching the server.js file though..  Took a look at it anyway and everything seems to look okay syntax-wise?

Comment: Sorry, the syntax error won't be in `server.js` but in a js file in your project. Is there not a line or two above that error explaining where it has come from?

Comment: Here's what I see when I put an un-closed brace in my `tester.js`: https://gist.github.com/3614984

Answer (score 0):

Check that you don't have duplicate and possibly conflicting versions of modules in your global and local paths.

```
npm list
```

and

```
npm list -g
```

should not list duplicate and/or conflicting versions of modules.
In my case I had *ws* installed locally and some of its dependencies were also on the global path.

My solution was to remove everything from my local path and just install everything globally.

Answer (score 0):

I've came across this error when I tried to start my server running on ubuntu on a well-known port (0-1023)

If that's the case, just run it as superuser (sudo)

In case that's not possible for you, check out this alternative (https://serverfault.com/a/112798)

Comment: FYI: If you click "share" at the bottom of any answer in the Stack Exchange network, you will get a direct link to that specific post. [This links here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25982206/892420) for example. Since the answer order is not fixed, that is the preferred way to reference other answers.

Comment: Oh, didn't know about that... Thx :)
I've updated my answer to it.

Answer (score 0):

in my experience was getting that error, caused by NPM and Node are not match version.

Need make sure NPM and Node are match (not mean same version)